# htaccess not giving the correct values

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get this to work, but I am having issues. When I go to `http://localhost/test/demo/` and echo out the value of `p` I get `demo`. but when I go to `http://localhost/test/demo/moretext/` the value of `p` is `index.php/moretext` why is it doing this? The `.htaccess` file is located inside the `test` directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/$ index.php?p=$1&file=$2
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this instead in one .htaccess file at `/test` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php       [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/test/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /test/index.php?p=%1&file=%2  [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php       [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/test/([^/]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*    /test/index.php?p=%1  [L]
```

Comment: nope, that just loads "wamp's" defalut page.

Comment: Still loads "wamp's" default page.

Comment: Changing `/index.php?p=%1` to `/test/index.php?p=%1` and changing `/index.php?p=%1&file=%2` to `/test/index.php?p=%1&file=%2` works!

Comment: You are right. I am not using the RewritBase. I will modify my answer.